# "Home" Page now only displaying the single latest post

Tags: posts, frontpage, single

We did have a normal dynamic post home page.( Arjuna X 1.6.11 by SRS Solutions) After selecting for a static, we returned the settings to our original settings. However, now we only have the single lastest post visible. I would love to get back the original settings.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the reading settings in the admin section (Settings->Reading).  Make sure that the setting "Blog pages show at most" didn't get changed.

If that doesn't fix it, try swapping back to the previous theme and see if it is anything to do with the theme's loop.

Otherwise, my last thought on it would be to check the page template and see how the loop is constructed in case there is a context where it's not looping.